# Hashie vs OpenStruct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What are the benefits of using the Hashie library over the Ruby native OpenStruct? I have heard that there are some benefits such as the Hashie library being faster than OpenStruct but I'm not sure if there is anything else available in Hashie that is not available in the native Ruby library.

Comment: Have you read the [Hashie README](https://github.com/intridea/hashie/blob/master/README.md)? It lists many, many features that OpenStruct doesn't have.

Comment: For what do you want to use Openstruct of Hashie? As you stated this question, I think it is too broad for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of performance, [this blog post](http://jgaskins.org/blog/2014/12/20/hashie-vs-openstruct-vs-poros) did some evaluation. The conclusion there was that allocating is faster for hashie, but accessing attributes is faster for OpenStruct (due to hashie using `MethodMissing`, for details see blog post).